Find a sequence of $Lˆ1$-summable functions with $|f_n(x)| \leq 1$ and some other properties
I am studying measure theory and summability/integrability in particular. One exercise is to find a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_n$ on $(0,\infty)$ satisfying the following criteria:
i) $\{f_n\}_n$ is $Lˆ1$-summable for all $n$, i.e. $\displaystyle\int_{(0,\infty)} |f_n(x)|< \infty$
ii) $|f_n(x)|\leq 1 \quad \forall x\forall n$
iii) $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = 0 \quad\forall x$
iv) $ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{(0,\infty)}f_n(x) dLˆ1 = 1$
There are no hints or solutions but I cannot come up with such a sequence. Any tips are welcome, thanks a lot!
Edit: I have tried $f_n = \chi_{(n, n+1]}$ which do not satisfy iii), $f_n =1-\frac{n}{x}$ which do not satisfy ii) AND iii), idk.

When you are faced with these problems, always look for easy solutions first. The easiest example of integrable functions are $\frac{1}{x^n}$, however there are two issues:

They are not integrable near $x=0$
They are not $\le1$ for all $x$

Both these problems can be solved by setting:
$$f_n(x)=
\begin{cases} 
      1 & x\in  (0,1) \\
      \frac{1}{x^n} & x\ge1 \\
   \end{cases}
$$
Unfortunately, this still doesn't satisfy (iii), so we might want to work with characteristichs instead.
And the example you provided works fine as well:
$$f_n(x)=\chi_{(n,n+1]}$$
It is of course integrable and $\le1$. It also satisfies condition (iii), since for fixed $x$ the interval where the function is not zero is "sliding" towards the right, so at one time it will surpass x
It clearly satisfies (iv), since the integral is always $1$, so it is a good answer.

wow haha that's beautiful, thanks a lot!

No problem :) you can accept the answer if you found it useful

I will, somehow there is a time limit for accepting answers earliest 5 mins after their being posted, probably to give you time for edits. :)

Oh, didn't know that

However, just as a side note, your function $\chi_{(n, n+1]}$ does satisfy condition (iii). For fixed $x$, the limit is $0$ since the interval where the function is not zero is "sliding" towards the right, so at one time it will surpass $x$. It also satisfies (iv)! So it was an acceptable answer as well.

I may be missing something, but it seems like your example doesn't satisfy (iii)? As defined, $f_n(x) = 1$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ and for all $n$.

@ktoi you are right, my bad! I will edit the question

A simple example, which you may have had in mind with your example, are rectangles that are getting wider and wider: $$f_n(x) := χ_{(0,n]}(x) \cdot \frac{1}{n}.$$ The area is obviously always 1 regardless of $n$, which is why iv. is fulfilled. The iii. is also fulfilled pointwise, since $1/n$ pushes the function towards 0 for fixed $x$. For ii. note $f_n(x) \leq \frac{1}{n} \leq 1 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. That i. is fulfilled is trivial, since each $f_n$ represents a step function.
